# How do I access my Models in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get familiar with CI and I have run into a problem while trying to implement my Model. I get the following error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Home::$OrderModel

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 12

My assumption was that I was breaking some convention with the naming of the Model. If
I change the line in question and call the model using all lower case:

$data['query'] = $this->ordermodel->get_all_workorder_names();

Nothing is returned to the view.. blank page; no source, no error.

Here is my model:

```
  <?php
class OrderModel extends Model{



function OrderModel()
{
    parent::Model();
    $db = $this->load->database();
}

function get_all_workorder_names()
{
    $this->db->select('name');
    $query = $this->db->get('WorkOrder');
    return $query->result();
}

}
?>
```

This is the calling controller:

```
<?php
class Home extends Controller{

function Home()
{
    parent::Controller();
    $this->load->model('ordermodel');
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
    function index()
    {
        $data['query'] = $this->OrderModel->get_all_workorder_names();
        $this->load->view('Header');
        //$this->load->view('Home',$data);
        $this->load->view('Footer');
    }
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? A side question: Is there a debugger available for PHP in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$this->ordermodel`.  The variable name will match whatever you use with `load->model()`

Answer (score 0):

For further reading, you can check out CodeIgniter's User Guide entry on loading models [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading).